# XML to XML transformation with hyperlink attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have an XML input which is similar to :

```
<data>
 <document docid="docfilename" />
 <record>ABC</record>
 <info>Testing</info>
 <case docid="casefilename">
  <details>
   Some random information
  </details>
  <author>Creator</author>
 </case>
 <page docid="pageurl">M Page</page>
</data>
```

The problem is, I want to transform this XML to exactly the same XML which would open in a browser and people could view the transformed XML, with just the docid attribute value replaced with an hyperlink to view the docfilename/casefilename/pageurl depending upon the link.

For e.g.

```
<data>
 <document docid="<a href="docfilename.html">docfilename</a>" />
 <record>ABC</record>
 <info>Testing</info>
 <case docid="<a href="casefilename.html">casefilename</a>">
  <details>
   Some random information
  </details>
  <author>Creator</author>
 </case>
 <page docid="<a href="http://www.example.com">pageurl</a>">M Page</page>
</data>
```

In the above output, you are able to view the  tag in the docid but user will be seeing only a link in the docid wherever found with a link to the file in the browser.

Any help to transform this xml in given format would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What?  That's not even valid XML now.

Comment: You're asking for output that is not well-formed. It's not legal to include an element in an attribute.

Comment: Also, you don't say where those links should come from.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, I know it is not a valid XML now. But as mentioned by Flynn1179, we can transform XML to a HTML displaying data in XML format, lets say using CSS in output, considering the output XML as CDATA and not actually XML. Simply I should have put XML to HTML transformation and output display in XML styling of the XML, but I wanted to know if there is any technique which I don't know to directly transform XML to XML with hyperlinks

Comment: @lwburk, I agree it is not well formed. Was just curious if it possible to have a direct xml to xml transformation, as I could do it using xml to html transformation. Those links are actually the filename + ext(html) mentioned in attribute which exists in the same folder where the XSLT is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're basically asking is how do you create hyperlinks that will show up when an XML document is opened in a browser?

There's no way to do this directly. A browser should only ever display the data in the document, it won't ever create hyperlinks like that.

You're only viable solution is to transform it to an actual HTML document that transforms every element/attribute into text, and overrides the attributes you want hyperlinks for. Here's a simple sheet that will do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>XML source</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <pre><xsl:apply-templates /></pre>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@docid">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="concat(.,'.html')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(),'=&quot;')" />
    <a href='{$url}'><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There won't be any pretty XML formatting or collapsing/expanding of nodes doing this, but you'll at least be able to display the XML with hyperlinks as needed. As @lwburk said, you haven't really specified where those links should come from; You should be able to adapt this to your needs though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. When I got this idea of transforming XML to XML for display purpose, so that an user can view the XML document with links, even I was sure that this could only be done through XML to HTML transformation but I wanted to know or say more curious to know if it could be done directly using XML to XML transformation, thank you for clarifying my doubt. I will try to implement the same using XML to HTML transformation now. :)